# Can you run consecutive While loops inside a User Defined Function in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, while-loop

I have written a UDF, inside of which I'm trying to run 4 consecutive while loops.  They are separate loops as they each use a slightly different input, however when the function is executed only the results of the first while loop are deposited in the data frame and I can't quite figure out why.

My code is below and should be executable:

```
# polydata is a set of specific numbers, but here a random sample is fine.
polydata = sample(1:60, 91)

# User Defined Function - argument "f.day" is an integer, I have been testing with "5"
My.Function = function(f.day) {
  # Fit polynomial
  forecast.day = f.day
  x = seq(forecast.day, forecast.day + 90, 1)
  y.2 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)))
  y.3 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)+(x^3)))
  y.4 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)+(x^3)+(x^4)))
  y.5 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)+(x^3)+(x^4)+(x^5)))


  df = as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = forecast.day+1, ncol = 4))
  colnames(df) = c("Quadratic", "Cubic", "Quartic", "Quintic")

  degree = 2
  i = 0
  df$Quadratic = c(rep(y.2[1], times = forecast.day + 1))
  while(i <= forecast.day + 1){
    j = 1
    while(j <= degree){
      df$Quadratic[i] = df$Quadratic[i] + y.2[j + 1] * i ^ j
      j = j + 1
    }
    i = i + 1
  }

  degree = 3
  i = 0
  df$Cubic = c(rep(y.3[1], times = forecast.day + 1))
  while(i <= forecast.day + 1){
    j = 1
    while(j <= degree){
      df$Cubic[i] = df$Cubic[i] + y.3[j + 1] * i ^ j
      j = j + 1
    }
    i = i + 1
  }

  degree = 4
  i = 0
  df$Quartic = c(rep(y.4[1], times = forecast.day + 1))
  while(i <= forecast.day + 1){
    j = 1
    while(j <= degree){
      df$Quartic[i] = df$Quartic[i] + y.4[j + 1] * i ^ j
      j = j + 1
    }
    i = i + 1
  }

  degree = 5
  i = 0
  df$Quintic = c(rep(y.5[1], times = forecast.day + 1))
  while(i <= forecast.day + 1){
    j = 1
    while(j <= degree){
      df$Quintic[i] = df$Quintic[i] + y.5[j + 1] * i ^ j
      j = j + 1
    }
    i = i + 1
  }
  return(df)
}
```

When I run the function in my test script, it appears that only the first While loop is being completed:

```
> My.Frame = My.Function(5)
> My.Frame
  Quadratic Cubic Quartic Quintic
1  39.43232    NA      NA      NA
2  38.54225    NA      NA      NA
3  37.66369    NA      NA      NA
4  36.79664    NA      NA      NA
5  35.94109    NA      NA      NA
6  35.09705    NA      NA      NA
```

Is there something missing or is it just not possible to run consecutive loops inside a function?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But in terms of the code, you are starting with degree = 3, you giving the wrong index  for the ys (e.g., y.3, y.4, y.5). These guys are indexed from 1 to 3 but when your j is equal 3 (the degree), then in `df$Cubic[i] = df$Cubic[i] + y.3[j + 1] * i ^ j`, you are indexing y.3[4] which will give you NA. Same with other ys i think.

Comment: @din Thanks for your comment, I was struggling to see what you were explaining however I finally understood - my mistake was in the generation of y.3, y.4, y.5.  The index being called did not exist. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Consecutive While loops can be run inside a function, the same way they would in normal script.  The error here is in the generation of the `y.2, y.3, y.4, y.5` vectors.  Here coefficients are being generated to specific degree - 2(quadratic), 3(cubic), 4(quartic) and 5(quintic).

y.2 is generated correctly, however the remainder are missing the necessary amount of `I` elements and so only 3 coefficients are generated for all of them (which is the correct amount for quadratic only). Therefore when j = 3 (the degree), then in `df$Cubic[i] = df$Cubic[i] + y.3[j + 1] * i ^ j`, it is indexing y.3[4] which will give NA as it does not exist.

The original code as such:

```
  y.2 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)))
  y.3 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)+(x^3)))
  y.4 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)+(x^3)+(x^4)))
  y.5 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)+(x^3)+(x^4)+(x^5)))
```

Should read as:

```
  y.2 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)))
  y.3 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)+I(x^3)))
  y.4 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)+I(x^3)+I(x^4)))
  y.5 = coef(lm(polydata ~ x + I(x^2)+I(x^3)+I(x^4)+I(x^5)))
```

Thus when now run the correct number of coefficients will be produced in relation the degree requested and the whole function will now produce the full data frame.